# Incomplete type only if not declared as pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having an object declared in a class:

```
class B;
class A{
  B object;
};
```

If I declare it B object; I get "object has incomplete type". If I declare it "B* object", the compilation ends successfully.

Why does that happens?
I'm using C++11;

Answer (score 3):

When declared as `B object;`, `A` needs the complete definition of `B` so the compiler knows how large it is, and therefore how large `A` is. When declared as a pointer, this information is not needed, because all pointers are the same size on a given platform.